# javascript setCaret function being inconsistant

Tags: javascript, html

Over the past couple of days I've read countless posts about setting the caret position in a content editable div. Finally I have come up with my own neat little function that works beautifully... the first time. If call the function again it seems to highlight an amount of seemingly random content of the page, including content outside the original div. My code is below. If anyone can cast any light on what might be going wrong and how I can fix it I would appreciate it.

(the "mod" variable is the content editable div)

```
var startNodeFound = false;
var endNodeFound = true;

function returnFocus(mod, start, end) {
mod.focus();
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();

setCaret(range, mod, start, "start", false);
if (end > 0) {
    endNodeFound = false
    setCaret(range, mod, end, "end", false);
}
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
}

function setCaret(range, node, offset, position) {
var i = 0;
var nodeCnt = node.childNodes.length;
while ((!startNodeFound || !endNodeFound) && i < nodeCnt) {
    var l = node.childNodes[i].length;
    if (l == undefined) {
        offset = setCaret(range, node.childNodes[i], offset, position)
    } else {
        if (offset <= l) {
            switch (position) {
                case "start":
                    if (!startNodeFound) {
                        startNodeFound = true;
                        range.setStart(node.childNodes[i], offset);
                    }
                    break;
                case "end":
                    if (!endNodeFound) {
                        endNodeFound = true;
                        range.setEnd(node.childNodes[i], offset);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            offset -= l
        }
    }
    i++;
}
return offset;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Had to set startNodeFound = false at end of returnFocus function.